# Is there a better query/code that will take less time to insert these data?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, sql-insert

I am trying to insert millions of rows into a table as shown in the below code. I want to insert first 3 million rows and then 30 million, 300 million and so on. probably stop at 300 million.

The reason I am doing this is that I want to test the table for partitioning. I want to test the table on a select or other statement when partitioned and not partitioned. I did the first insert (3 million rows) and this took more than 30 minutes.

Is there an easy way to insert the data that will take less time?

```
declare
  c_id  number := 0 ;
begin        
  while (c_id <= 3000000)
  loop
    INSERT all

      when c_id <= 500000 then
      into city
      values(c_id,'City' || c_id || sysdate,'NY',c_id + 500 || sysdate)

      when c_id between 500001 and 1000000 then
      into city
      values(c_id,'City' || c_id || sysdate,'CA',c_id + 500 || sysdate)

      when  c_id between 1000001 and 1500000 then 
      into city
      values(c_id,'City' || c_id || sysdate,'TX',c_id + 500 || sysdate)

      when c_id between 1500001 and 2000000 then 
      into city
      values(c_id,'City' || c_id || sysdate,'WA',c_id + 500 || sysdate)

      when c_id between 2000001 and 2500000 then
      into city
      values(c_id,'City' || c_id || sysdate,'NC',c_id + 500 || sysdate)

      when c_id > 2500000 then
      into city
      values(c_id,'City' || c_id || sysdate,'SC',c_id + 500 || sysdate)

    select 1 from dual;

      c_id := c_id + 1;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: You could use a tally table to generate the source data rather than using a loop: `SELECT c_id, State FROM ( SELECT ROWNUM c_id, CASE WHEN ROWNUM BETWEEN 1 AND 50000 THEN 'NY' ELSE 'CA' END State FROM ALL_CATALOG CROSS JOIN ALL_CATALOG)`. It depends whether the performance issue is in the `INSERT` or `SELECT`

Comment: Hi Nick, I want to partition the table being created. what table is created in the above query?

Comment: @daniman8 For bulk inserts use forall and bulk collect concepts.

Comment: You may use dbms_parallel_execute and run by chunks size.

Comment: maybe...you could have a data file setup an an external table and use INSERT AS SELECT from the external table to the part table you're testing.

Comment: If you insert large amount of rows, consider using /*+ APPEND */ to avoid redo generation (read carefully about direct path insert first - [http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#i2063953](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#i2063953)). Don't use row-by-row approach and PL/SQL loops if not necessary - context switching between SQL and PL/SQL is enormous. FORALL processes it in two context switches but it's not needed at all when the source is a table or a set of data that can be simply generated using SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would generate the test data:

```
HUSQVIK@panel_management> CREATE TABLE CITIES (ID NUMBER NOT NULL, CITY VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL, STATE VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL, SOME_DATA VARCHAR2(255)) NOLOGGING;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
HUSQVIK@panel_management> ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML;

Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
HUSQVIK@panel_management> INSERT /*+ append */ INTO CITIES
  2  WITH STATES AS (
  3     SELECT 'NY' STATE, 1 ID_OFFSET FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 'CA' STATE, 2 ID_OFFSET FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5     SELECT 'TX' STATE, 3 ID_OFFSET FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6     SELECT 'WA' STATE, 4 ID_OFFSET FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7     SELECT 'NC' STATE, 5 ID_OFFSET FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8     SELECT 'SC' STATE, 6 ID_OFFSET FROM DUAL
  9  ),
 10  GENERATOR AS (
 11     SELECT /*+ materialize cardinality(5000000) */ (LEVEL - 1) * 6 ID FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5000000
 12  )
 13  SELECT ID + ID_OFFSET, 'City' || (ID + ID_OFFSET) || SYSDATE, STATE, ID + 500 || SYSDATE
 14  FROM GENERATOR CROSS JOIN STATES;

30000000 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:13.08
HUSQVIK@panel_management>
```

30 million rows generated and inserted in 13 seconds. But this is without any indexes. Each index will slow down the insert significantly even though /*+ APPEND */ optimizes their maintenance as well.

Comment: This is probably the fastest way.  But watch out for errors like `ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation`.  Depending on memory settings there may not be enough memory to generate all the rows at once.  It may be necessary to break the statement into smaller chunks.  It wouldn't be as fast as doing it all at once, but it would still be much faster than row-by-row.

Comment: This limitation is not that much relevant to this case because it's not a problem to have multiple small generator tables like

`WITH GENERATOR1 AS (SELECT LEVEL * 1000 V1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5000), GENERATOR2 AS (SELECT LEVEL V1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000) SELECT ... FROM GENERATOR1, GENERATOR2`

to generate as many rows as needed with minimal memory requirements.

Comment: Hello all thank you for the help. @Husqvik, yes you are right. Using the query you suggested is fast but when I try to partition the table I am getting an error:                                                                                        ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition. The partition is: Partition by list(cityregion)(Partition partion1 values('NY','NJ') tablespace system,Partition partion2 values ('CA','TX','WA') tablespace sysaux,
Partition partion3 values ('NC', 'IL') tablespace users,
Partition partion4 values ('KA','SC','NV') tablespace LARGE_TBL)

Comment: I didn't specify the column list in INSERT INTO, are you sure the CITYREGION is the third column in the table? In non-example code always use explicit lists and names, so `INSERT /*+ append */ INTO CITIES (ID, CITY, STATE, SOME_DATA)` should be in my example.

Comment: @Husqvik , thank you I figured out what the problem was from your hint.